# Use Google Authentication for Java webportal with SSO

Tags: java, json, oauth, google-oauth

I am new to GA(OAuth).

I have few queries while using Google authentication on java web based portal. 
1) How and where do I configure my web-portal(e.g. https://abc.xyz.com)?

2) If I have 100 user base, in that case do i have to create each user's account in order to achieve authentication from Google?
     If yes then how shall i map them for above portal?

3) I have used http://ocpsoft.org/java/setting-up-google-oauth2-with-java/
Is there any way to avoid maintenance of clientID, Clientsecret or JSon at my web application level and can still achieve secure authentication from GA?

4) how can i implement SSO?
Any early help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login)

Comment: Any reply would be helpful...

Comment: Do you just want to allow login using Google?

Comment: Basically I want to perform authentication and login both for a user before redirected to redirectURI(my web portal)

Comment: Along with google authentication/login i also want to implement SSO.